# How to access web server running on host OS from inside a microk8s pod?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, microk8s

I would like to have a web server running in a pod reaching a web server running on my host OS.

To do that i need to have the ip or dns of my host inside microk8s.

Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Downward API`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/) to get host IP details.

Example:

```
env:
   - name: NODE_IP
     valueFrom:
       fieldRef:
         fieldPath: status.hostIP
```